# << and >> do not give « » (guillemets)

Tags: punctuation, font-encodings

***Context***

```
~$ latex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
```

with this *.tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Gummi|065|=)
\title{\textbf{Test ULysse}}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\begin{document}

% \maketitle

\section{ \(26^e\) épisode Où Achille...}

\noindent
Il dit : << C'est Ulysse ! >> ...
```

***Question :*** How to correct this result :

- two characters `<<` gives a reversed one : `‼` (dots are upside) and not `«`.
- two characters `>>` gives a reversed one : `⁇` (dots are upside) and not `»`

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Also consider the use of `$\langle\langle$` and `$\rangle\rangle$` (`amsmath`) instead of `<<` and `>>` respectively.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Nice. I've marked my answer as solved

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Interesting, but  `« openn...close»` are specific french `"` to report oral sentences in correct typo.

Comment: "Pardon my French" as they say over here.  Of course, over here, that expression is also used to signify that what is about to be spoken is not suitable for small children to hear. ;^)

Comment: @cl-r Welcome. As you might know considering your reputation, we don't edit the question with the answer. Either Ulrike answers or you can answer providing the same information if she doesn't want to.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- Sorry, just a reflex... coming after a recent answer on another usage's forum where I put a questiont :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typing `<<` for « and `>>` for » is provided only if you load the T1 encoding.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Test ULysse}
\author{}
\date{}

\maketitle

\section{26\ieme{} épisode Où Achille...}

Il dit : << C'est Ulysse ! >> ...

\end{document}
```

Note `\ieme` for the superscript e.

However, this doesn't really take care of the spaces around the guillemets and you risk having a line break after « or before ».

The right way is using `\og` and `\fg` or, even better `«` and `»` directly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{«}{\og\ignorespaces}
\newunicodechar{»}{\unskip\fg}

\begin{document}

\title{Test ULysse}
\author{}
\date{}

\maketitle

\section{26\ieme{} épisode Où Achille...}

Il dit : \og C'est Ulysse ! \fg{} ...

Il dit : « C'est Ulysse ! » ...

Il dit : «C'est Ulysse!» ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- By all means, load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`.
- Consider loading the `csquotes` package with the option `french=guillemets`, in addition to loading the `babel` package with the option `french`. Then, write `\enquote{C'est Ulysse!}` and let LaTeX handle the exact positioning of the quote marks.
- Don't write `\(26^e\) épisode` in the argument of a sectioning header. Instead, write `26\up{e} épisode` -- note: *no math mode needed*. (`\ieme{}` works too.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\begin{document}

\section{ 26\up{e} épisode Où Achille \dots}

\noindent
Il dit: <<$\;$C'est Ulysse!$\;$>> % "\;" for "thickspace"

\noindent
Il dit: \enquote{C'est Ulysse!} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{fontspec}` also results in guillemets.

Comment: @Mico: `frenchb` has the shortcuts `\up{e}`, or, even simpler: `\ieme`, instead of the clumsy `\textsuperscript{e}`.

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks for pointing out these alternatives. I'll make the change.

Comment: @Bernard -- `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}` hangs, like `\usepackage[francais]{babel}`, but `\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}` is OK, where is the mistake ?

Comment: A better french typo should be :   `Il dit\,: <<\,C'est Ulysse\,!\,>>` — `''` is used before `! : ; ? »` and on the good side of  `—` and after `«`

Comment: If I remember well, `frenchb` shouldn't be used any more, but `french`, and preferably  set as a document class option

Comment: You're right: the so-called ‘high punctuation’ requires an unbreakable space before (which is not necessarily a thin space – it depends on the punctuation). Normally, you shouldn't have to use the `\,`  spacings by yourself: frenchb does it for you automagically.

Comment: @cl-r - Using `\enquote` from the `csquotes` package frees the writer from having to remember how much space (thinspace?, medspace?, thickspace?) to insert between the quoted word(s) and the guillemets. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, use the `fontenc` package with the `T1` option, and for more typographically correct results you can use the `\og` and `\fg` commands of the `Frenchb` extension (which provides the `french` option of `babel`). However, I think like `egreg` that the best way to enter French guillemets is to enter those guillemets directly, without having to enter `\og` or `\fg` nor  `<<` or `>>` (I'm assuming you use a French AZERTY keyboard: French guillemets, `«` and `»`, are available on those). However I differ about the way to do this: `Frenchb` has an option for this, no need to use the `newunicode` package pointed par `egreg`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{og = «, fg = »}
\begin{document}
Il dit : « c'est Ulysse ! »…
\end{document}
```